# How to fire 404 to all non-canonical urls?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Could somebody point me to htaccess rules, which would fire the 404 error to any page, which hasn't the canonical tag?

I thought about something like this snippet could achieve (not sure, whether it is correct, but looks like it would):

```
function resolve_canonical($canonical,$location = "404"){
    $current_url= "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($current_url !== $canonical){
        if($location == "404"){
            // header("location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/404");
            // header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            readfile('404.php');
            exit();      
        }elseif($location == "redirect"){
            header("location: ".$canonical);          
            exit();  
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just do that with .htaccess, you don't have access to php's variables like that. This function will never fire.

One possibility could be a GET parameter, you might be able to use that in your htaccess, but it woon't be easy.

The way you are doing now is fine, just place this early in your code so no unneccesary code runs.

---

You're code can get shorter (might overdid it, but to show you it can be done):

```
function resolve_canonical($canonical,$location = "404"){
    if($canonical !== "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ){
        if($location == "404"){          header("location: "/404", true, 404); }
        elseif($location == "redirect"){ header("location: ".$canonical);      }
        exit;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn! Could you help me to modify this code to redirect user to the canonical URL instead of firing 404?

Comment: just combine the 1st and 2nd header in my example short code :)

Comment: not sure i understand correctly...like this:?function resolve_canonical($canonical,$location = "404"){
    if($canonical !== "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ){
        if($location == "404"){          header("location: ".$canonical); }
        exit;  
    }
}

Comment: `header("location: ".$canonical, true, 404);`